# Is there a CDN for dgrid?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dgrid in my project and I am currently building a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/ZCFyL/) of it.
For including dgrid, I tried using the following GitHub URL but it doesnt work.

```
https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/Grid.js
```

How do I get this working?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/ZCFyL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont believe there is a CDN for dgrid... Only the dojo cdn is available. If you want to use a custom module alongside of a cdn check this out...
[Custom Modules With Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/cdn/)